# SQLalchemy: Select all rows which have a many-to-many relationship to another table

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following database setup

```
descriptors = db.Table('descriptors',
   db.Column('object_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('object.id')),
   db.Column('descriptor_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('descriptor.id'))
)

class Descriptor(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(2000))
    ...
    objects = db.relationship('Object', secondary=descriptors, backref=db.backref('descriptors'))
def __repr__(self):
    return '<Descriptor %r>' % (self.id)  

class Object(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
def __repr__(self):
    return '<Object %r>' % (self.id)
```

I want to select all objects which have a descriptor. Meaning I want to select all objects which have an object_id in the descriptors table. But since I can't query the descriptor table directly I don't quite know how to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the any operator in you filter, e.g.:

```
session.query(Object).filter(Object.descriptors.any())
```

Comment: If it worked, please accept it as the answer. Thank you!

Comment: is there a reference for the any() function... I am wondering whether there is a function to actually count the rows?

Comment: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#counting has documentation for the most common query operators